# Question about rejected edit that doesn't follow regular rejection reasons

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, rejected-edits, rejection-reasons

Edit in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/24554150

for answer in question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3002635/2757283

The reason used for rejection was:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

which, I believe, was for the lack of an appropriate reason.

While the edit doesn't make the answer easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or (probably) more accessible, it is neither superfluous, nor actively harming readability. The edit, as stated in the edit comment, separates answer from extra info.

So what is the real reason for rejection?

Answer (score 19):

Your edit is completely superfluous.

The extra info is not "extra" or optional as it gives advice to a good practice.

Putting P.S doesn't make the post even a little bit easier to read either (=no improvement).

Comment: It is advice but it is not part of the answer to the question which is the point.

Comment: @DanAlexson90 yes, it is part of the answer. The OP was trying to compare integers with strings on his question so that part of the answer is crucial.

Comment: If the question was why the `SELECT` query doesn't work - then fine, one answer.

Comment: The question was, How do I add indices to MySQL tables? The answer was given, together with the extra advice.

Comment: @DanAlexson90 you're encouraging bad practices then. Imagine I want to do a query that does X but my code is SQL-injection vulnerable. People will answer X and also tell that my code is bad and also tell me how can I make the query not vulnerable. If this part is missed, my code can have problems later on.

Comment: I am ALL for good practices. Hence why my edit wasn't about removing the part, it was, programmatically speaking, separation of concerns - a good practice :)

Comment: @DanAlexson90 having a paragraph already separates concerns so entering a "P.S" does not make your edit easier to read.

Comment: It is paragraph because it isn't code (technical reasons) not because for separation reasons. It still looks like you need one thing for the other.

Comment: The irony is, if that PS was there in the first place, no one would be trying to remove it.

Comment: @DanAlexson90 you're supposed to [remove any noise](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts) from posts. Of course we should not hunt for every single post to follow this but if you found it you should remove it.